# VHDL: slice a various part of an array

Tags: arrays, vhdl, slice

I have a `STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (0 to 639)`.
On an incoming signal I have to iterate through this vector and get next 2 bits of it.

I'm trying to make something like, with an integer `counter`:

```
counter := counter+1;
MyVar := Data((counter*2) to ((counter*2)+1));
```

I get the following:

> Error (10394): VHDL error at module.vhd(227): left bound of range must be a constant

upd: the following was suggested by @user1155120: writing every single bit of vector to every single corresponding bit of MyVar

```
MyVar(0) := Data(counter * 2);
MyVar(1) := Data(counter * 2 + 1);
```

Works fine as long as I use the 2bit `MyVar`, but what if i want to use a 16-32-80bit variable? Problem avoided, but not solved.

Comment: what is the type of `counter` ?

Comment: @scary_jeff variable counter: integer range 0 to 639; -- later (if = 630 then = 0)

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24192103/vhdl-quartus-left-bound-of-range-must-be-a-constant

Comment: @Qiu i have no need to write into the array. i need to get data from it. I'm writing in it using constants, but need to read dynamically

Comment: @Vanechka: slicing works the same way for both actions.

Comment: @Qiu so you suggest me to convert my integer to an integer of what?))

Comment: @Qiu if your advice worked, i'd say thanks and be happy to move on, but unfortunately, it doesn't...

Comment: What toolchain are you using?

Comment: @scary_jeff you mean IDE and hardware?

Comment: Also note that this fails spectacularly for values of `counter` greater than 319.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googling shows the error message is from Quartus II (See [ID: 10394](http://quartushelp.altera.com/13.1/mergedProjects/msgs/msgs/evrfx_vhdl_left_bound_of_range_not_constant.htm)). The LRM reference it provides isn't particularly helpful, it's a limitation on synthesis that you can't define a variable width word size for a multiplexer. Not smart enough to detect both bounds are referenced to counter.

What happens if you express a multiplexer for each bit of `MyVar` separately? (Indexed name instead of slice name, two variable assignments to `MyVar(1)` and `MyVar(0)`).

```
MyVar(0) := Data(counter * 2);
MyVar(1) := Data(counter * 2 + 1);
```

This thread [need a help with strange error" left bound of the range must be a constant "](http://www.alteraforum.com/forum/showthread.php?t=33497) suggests using a loop to assign each bit of the target slice range, which is also using an indexed name on a per element basis.

```
for i in MyVar'RANGE loop
    MyVar(i) := Data(counter * 2 + i);
end loop;
```

`counter` only needs half the index range, you're always multiplying it by 2.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In my real module I started using the same construct with separate indexing of MyVar, yesterday, it seems to work fine with 2bit vectors. what if i need a slice of 8bit width, 16 bit, 80 bit? The error is avoided, but not solved, I guess. Speaking of a LOOP, in the case you shown, will have a bigger delay with passing this part? I do my best not to use loops in time-reliable parts of my code..

Comment: A loop statement should generate the same hardware. In simulation "A loop statement includes a sequence of statements that is to be executed repeatedly, zero or more times." When synthesized the loop repetitions are parallelized. When simulated you likely couldn't notice the difference in execution time, everything operates element at a time anyway.  To deal with powers of 2 widths change `MyVar(i) := Data(counter * 2 + i);` to  `MyVar(i) := Data(counter * MyVar'LENGTH + i);`  It's not a language error, it's a synthesis tool limitation.